# Display base64 TIFF on img or canvas tag

Tags: base64, tiff

I have an error with this lib:
http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/upload.html

In the demo page, all is ok. but when I try to use on my machine I got this message:

> 1.tiff: JPEG compression support is not configured.
>   1.tiff: Sorry, requested compression method is not configured.

I have a `base64tiff` and I want to show that image on canvas o img.

I've tried on codepen and It works fine too, I've supposed that it could be a server configuration.